# CursorIndexOutOfBoundException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: java, android, sqlite

it's me once more, having problems with sqlite for Android

I currently get a "`CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1"
However, I had this exception with Index -1 then inserted a `cursor.moveToFirst(),` then I had this with index 0 , then did `cursor.moveToNext();`
What I wanna do with my code? I want the information of a selected item (that's why the selectionArgs are there with sQueryid. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Cursor c = a.managedQuery(uri, 
            projection, //projection
            "_ID=?", //selection string
            new String[]{sQueryid}, //selection args array of strings
            DepotTableMetaData.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER); //sort order
    c.moveToFirst();
    c.moveToNext();
    int iqrcode = c.getColumnIndex(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_QRCODE);     
    int iname = c.getColumnIndex(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_NAME);
    int iamount = c.getColumnIndex(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_AMOUNT);
    int iunit = c.getColumnIndex(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_UNIT);
    int ippu = c.getColumnIndex(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_PPU);
    int itotal = c.getColumnIndex(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_TOTAL);
    int icomment = c.getColumnIndex(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_COMMENT);


        //Gather values
        String id = c.getString(Integer.parseInt(queryid.toString()));

        String name = c.getString(iname);
        String amount = c.getString(iamount);
        String unit = c.getString(iunit);
        String ppu = c.getString(ippu);
        String total = c.getString(itotal);
        String comment = c.getString(icomment);
        String qrcode = c.getString(iqrcode);

        String[] info = new String[]{id,name,amount,unit,ppu,total,comment,qrcode};
```

Comment: OK GUYS, I think my problem is now elsewhere, anyways thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`moveToFirst` takes you to the first (and only) result. The next call to `moveToNext` takes you to the second result (index 1) which doesn't exist.

Try removing the `c.moveToNext();`

Comment: "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException", if i click the 3rd item of my listview, if i click the first item i get IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 8 failed >.<

to select the item i want to view i use an onItemClickListener which also returns an id, is this even the same ID as used in the database?

edit:// my little book (1200 pages) here tells me, it returns the ID of the adapter used...

Comment: If you are having new problems perhaps you should open up a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `cursor.moveToFirst();` and there you are. Since `moveToFirst()` takes the cursor pointer to the first record and thats what you need. Do not do `moveToNext()` after you did `moveToFirst()` as you did in the snippet.

Comment: uhm i am only requesting 1 row of items.... i am not interested in more, dunno why i should loop it?

Comment: Ow, sorry, I thought you you are fetching a tons of data. :) Move the `cursor.moveToFirst();` and there you are. Since `moveToFirst()` takes the cursor pointer to the first record and thats what you need. Do not do `moveToNext()` after you did `moveToFirst()` as you did in the snippet.

Comment: read my code.. it's there... as also the guy before you suggested, i removed the moveToNext() and now i am getting 2 more error messages, depending on what i select on my listview 
quote: "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException", if i click the 3rd item of my listview, if i click the first item i get IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 8 failed >.< to select the item i want to view i use an onItemClickListener which also returns an id, is this even the same ID as used in the database? edit:// my little book (1200 pages) here tells me, it returns the ID of the adapter used...

Comment: Could you post the listview code, and onItemClick listener code  and how you instanciate the adapter on pastebin.com?

Comment: narf i found a new posibility  for the error, still it didn't work... I didn't include BaseColumns._ID in my projection, but still with it, the same error appears

Comment: Ok. No there is no more CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException but ArrayIOBE...check here you are overlapping array length. Makesure you dont overlap when you are filling the array with elements.

Comment: hmm i did some more logging and it seems i can't return my 'String[] info = new String[]{id,name,amount,unit,ppu,total,comment,qrcode};' with 'return info'

Answer (score 0):

You need to include more information in your post; the code shows variables that are being used but we have no idea what they are (uri, project, sQueryid, etc.).  You have an sQueryid String and also are trying to send the String value of a variable called queryid to the parseInt method--are these the same variables, with a typo?  If not, you should try alternate naming so it's less confusing.

We also can't see what method thsi code is in; you mention you're getting issues when clicking on your ListView, but is this where the code resides?  If so, calling moveToFirst() and/or moveToNext() on your Cursor is not what you want, and you wouldn't be getting the cursor by caling managedQuery there.  Instead, you'd want to use the position information passed in to the method and the ListView's adapter.  With a little more of your code, I could give an example.

If you're just trying to cycle through all of the rows in your Cursor query, you probably want to do something like this:

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_NAME));
    String amount = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_AMOUNT));
    // ...
    // do something with the data for this row
}
```

**Edit (per the code listed in your comment):**

I think your issue is with the id that you're passing to the `ShowActivity` guy.  In your ShowActivity class, make a class-level variable for your `Cursor` you're using on the `SimpleCursorAdapter` for the `ListView` so that you can access it in other methods.  So, something like:

```
public class ShowActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    Cursor mCursor;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
        mCursor = managedQuery(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
        // ...
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_entry, mCursor, columns, to);
        // ...
```

Then, your `onItemClick` method should look something like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View target, int position, long id) {
    Log.d("ShowActivity", "clicked @ " + position);
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    final String itemId = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    Intent openAdvanced = new Intent(ShowActivity.this,AdvancedViewActivity.class);
    openAdvanced.putExtra("ID", itemId);
    startActivity(openAdvanced);
}
```

Comment: pastebin.com/Fs4JCcQ8 i only want 1 item with _ID = the variable sQueryid ... so no need to loop

Answer (score 0):

I stopped getting this problem after I started coding it like this

```
if (c != null ) {
    Cursor c = sql.rawQuery("SELECT...");
    c.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        //do something
    c.moveToNext();
    }
}
```