# How to read more than one record of one row from SQLite table?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor, where-clause

I got a database called test_database.
And I got a table called `tbl_marks`.
In `tbl_marks` there are following rows:

- _id
- name
- subid
- gewicht
- datum

There are 4 entries. two with subid 1 and the other 2 with subid 2.

Now I like to do following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_marks WHERE subid = 1;
```

So finally I like to list all marks with `subid` 1, 2, 3 or what ever in a listview.

How can I do that by cursor?

I was trying to learn it by a tutorial but it failed...

[Higherpass Android Tutorial Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/)

[Anddev Working with the sqlite database - Cursors](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_the_sqlite-database_-_cursors-t319.html)

Code: The commented part is what I got before (it listed everything)

```
private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list

    mDbHelper.open_database_rw();
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, subid, name, mark, gewicht, datum FROM tbl_marks ORDER BY subid;", null);
    startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    if (mCursor != null) {
         int intName = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("subid");

          do {
              teststring = mCursor.getString(intName);

              String[] from = new String[] { dbHelper.KEY_NAME_MARKS, dbHelper.KEY_MARK_MARKS, dbHelper.KEY_GEWICHT_MARKS, dbHelper.KEY_DATUM_MARKS};
              int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txt_marks_row, R.id.txt_note, R.id.txt_gewicht, R.id.txt_datum};


              SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.show_marks, mCursor, from, to);
              setListAdapter(notes);
          } while (mCursor.moveToNext());

    }
```

LogCat says that the column subid does not exists. But it's there and the db has been opened.

```
02-07 11:30:00.500: D/dalvikvm(9913): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 54K, 50% free 2694K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 56ms
02-07 11:30:00.535: D/dalvikvm(9913): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4K, 50% free 2698K/5379K, external 13K/523K, paused 27ms
02-07 11:30:10.457: D/AndroidRuntime(9913): Shutting down VM
02-07 11:30:10.457: W/dalvikvm(9913): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40235568)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.marco.notenha/test.marco.notenha.mark}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'subid' does not exist
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1664)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'subid' does not exist
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at test.marco.notenha.mark.fillData(mark.java:180)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at test.marco.notenha.mark.onCreate(mark.java:70)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1628)
02-07 11:30:10.457: E/AndroidRuntime(9913):     ... 11 more
```

That's line 180: int intName = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("subid");

```
02-07 11:52:26.304: D/dalvikvm(10075): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 48K, 50% free 2694K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 38ms
02-07 11:52:26.339: D/dalvikvm(10075): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4K, 50% free 2698K/5379K, external 13K/523K, paused 30ms
02-07 11:52:29.433: D/AndroidRuntime(10075): Shutting down VM
02-07 11:52:29.433: W/dalvikvm(10075): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40235568)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.marco.notenha/test.marco.notenha.mark}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1664)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at test.marco.notenha.mark.fillData(mark.java:183)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at test.marco.notenha.mark.onCreate(mark.java:70)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1628)
02-07 11:52:29.437: E/AndroidRuntime(10075):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "subid" column must be in the SELECT column list in order for the *mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("subid")* call to return it:

```
SELECT _id, name, mark, gewicht, datum, subid FROM tbl_marks ORDER BY subid;
```

**Edit:**

Now you need to call mCursor.moveToFirst() and check that it returns "true" (i.e. the result list is not empty). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843639/cursorindexoutofboundexception-index-1-requested-with-a-size-of-1). As an example:

```
if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int intName = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("subid");
    do {
          teststring = mCursor.getString(intName);

          ...
    } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did that! But now I got another error:  Index -1 requested, with a size of 3. LogCat View has been added

Comment: See the update to my answer, you need to position your cursor and check the query results are not empty.

Comment: Thanks dude it's not crashing longer :) I'll try to get only those values with a subid x and list them and on another side with another subid. Hope i'll do it!

Answer (score 1):

```
myDB = openOrCreateDatabase("tbl_marks", MODE_PRIVATE, null);


Cursor mCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM tbl_marks ORDER BY name;", null);
startManagingCursor(mCursor);
if (myCursor != null) {
     int intName = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name");
     if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
          String strName = myCursor.getString(intName);

     /* do {
          String strName = myCursor.getString(intName);
        } while (myCursor.moveToNext());*/ 

    }

}
```

if you wanna show the results in a listview:

```
myDB = openOrCreateDatabase("tbl_marks", MODE_PRIVATE, null);


Cursor mCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT name, mark, gewicht, datum FROM tbl_marks ORDER BY subid;", null);
startManagingCursor(mCursor);
if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this, // Context.
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        mCursor,
                        new String[] {"name"},
                        new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Don't I have to put it into a while? Because I have to read every record with subid x.

Comment: I edited my answer. And i think there is some try/catch missing. But i think eclipse (or whatever you're using) will tell you that, too. :)

Comment: Jup I tried it. But there is still a mistake which I can't figure out. I edited my question and posted the logcat view.

Comment: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3

Comment: Sure that the columns name is really 'subid'? what i noticed is, that you have an empty selection: "SELECT _id, , [...]"

Comment: Yes I am sure it's called subid. I checked in code and in database.
That has been fixed with the empy selection. Still same error

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_marks order by subid
```

then by using the cursor you can retrieve the records tha you want.

Comment: I don't have any problems with SQL, DDL or DML. I just don't know how to read them through the table and list them. I did add some code. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: Now I got follwing error: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3